# why pyspark reads avro multiple times?

Tags: pyspark, avro, lazy-evaluation

I use pyspark to read avro data using list of paths created from blob names.

Why does pyspark run two jobs both with same description which means to me I read avro data twice? Is the reason that I do not provide schema when I read avro?

I would expect to read data once only. What am I doing wrong and how to mitigate from it? I load 1.3 TB of data in this avro read.

```
Job Id 1 Tasks 11452
Job Id 0 Tasks 11252
```

I see the data is saved once Job 0 is completed.
Job 0 takes ~31 min and job 1 takes ~15 min.

this is the code

```
blob_names: List[str] = ...
blobs_filtered: List[str] = ...

(
    spark
    .read
    .format('avro')
    .load(blobs_filtered, infer_schema=True, header=True)
    .select(*["qname", "user_ip", "config_id"])
    .where("qname != '' and qname is not NULL")
    .withColumn("date", F.lit(config.process_date))
    .repartition(200)
    .write
    .format("delta")
    .partitionBy("date")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .save(config.output_table_path)
)
```

Comment: Could you share more about what kind of stage and task in both job `1` and `2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the spark code, I think spark tries to infer your schema from some sample files if you don't have a explicit schema and then read all the files. that's why you have two jobs:
https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/0ccfff0912fa176efa2d76537c99acba876d3b57/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/avro/DefaultSource.scala

Comment: this is what i thought might be the case also. I will create avro schema and execute the job again to see if there is any difference. i will come back within next few days af if it is the reason then I will hit accept button on your answer.

Comment: do you know any good way to create schema for avro files when there are many columns but I want to read 3 out of n columns? I will use this https://itnext.io/automate-generating-avro-schemas-from-a-spark-dataframe-6e8956f03500

Comment: If you are using only 3 columns, why not just define your schema with that 3 cols but to automate it using this tool? If you really need it, you only need to add a filter on the field name: if(field.name in ["fieldName1", "fieldName2", "fieldName3"]): between line 33 and 34